# how to personilize "bootstrap-generators" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, sass

Right now I'm feeling really dumb but I can't find a way to personalize the color in the gem "bootstrap-generators" I've tried to edit the color in bootstrap-variables.scss but is not working.
Bootstrap is correctly installed because it works and I tried to delete the cache folder to force rails to rebuild it but it' pointless.

I'm using rails 4.2.0 and bootstrap-generators 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the following things for investigate problem:

1) Shutdown Rails app, clear cache (use `rake tmp:clear`), change color variable and run application again.

2) Try to broke `bootstrap-variables.scss` file. If your application really using(compile) it you will see a error.

3) Try to change any other variable. Probably you a trying to change wrong variable.

Comment: I've tried and adding some random character it broke the app but nothing appened wen I change ANY I don't know if is right but the bootstrap-variables.css is empty

Comment: Can you provide your application.css file?

Comment: Try to use [this](https://gist.github.com/maxd/fc27e0393949f747b87e) application.css. As you can see I have removed `boostrap` because it will be included in `bootstrap-generator` and moved `require_tree` and `require_self` statements to the end of file.